# How to filter column in chart web part?

Tags: filter, chart-web-part

I have a list with 3 columns, Month, volvo, benz. I have created a chart which contains 2 series, volvo and benz. It shows 2 series based on month, for example for jan, it shows value volvo & benz bar, for feb, it shows different value of volvo & benz. Now i want to filter the chart by column i.e if i type volvo, all volvo bar should be filtered and if i type benz, all benz bar should be filtered.

How to do it? I tried with text filter but in that you have to give a value from the column whereas i want all values of a particular column.

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps:

Have the chart get its data through a connection to the list web part.

Briefly:

1. Add both chart and list webpart to a page
2. Edit the chart webpart and have it pull connection from the list web part
3. Filter the list webpart columns accordingly (volve or benz)
4. This should update the chart to the filter of the list

Answer (score 0):

Using the free Google Chart Web Part from Amrein Engineering, I was able to complete something similar to your request.

[Google Chart Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5749)

Comment: I cant use third party tools. Is there anyway by in-build sharepoint chart web part?